# Inserting a new row in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.source.getActiveRange();
  // 3 is column C
  if (range.getColumn() == 3) {
  if (range.getValue() != "") {
    sheet.insertRowAfter(range.getRow());
  }
}
}​
```

When the script inserts a row, I would like it to type " " (a space) in column 8 (h) of the new line. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.source.getActiveRange();
  // 3 is column C
  if (range.getColumn() == 3) {
    if (range.getValue() !== " ") {
      sheet.insertRowAfter(range.getRow());
    }
  }
}​
```

Certainly, replace your actual code with this.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. Do I add this to my above script or replace it? I added it and now it doesn't add a row when it is supposed to

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
if (range.getvalue() != "") {
   sheet.insertRowAfter(range.getRow());
   var newRange = e.source.getCell(4, 8);
   newRange.setValue(' ');
}
```